# jqGrid - binding dropdown or button in each row

Tags: jquery, xml, drop-down-menu, binding, jqgrid

Using jqGrid 4.5.2 & trying to put a dropdown box or a button (depending on a value in the row data) as needed.  The contents of the dropdown box I am storing in a variable in the page & assigning it in a custom formatter.  The dropdown box is as follows:

```
<select id="rlist" class="choices" name="rlist">
<option value="0" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Message</option>
<option value="7">Message2</option>
<option value="8">Message3</option>
<option value="9">Message4</option>
<option value="10">Message5</option>
</select>
```

The code for the button is:

```
"<input name='reviewedBtn' class='cbox' style='height:90%;width:60%' type='submit' value='Reviewed' />";
```

I am retrieving the following data in `XML` format & displaying it in the jqGrid.

```
<Rowset>
<Row>
<msgTxt>Test Message3</msgTxt>
<SendTime>2013-06-18T15:05:59</SendTime>
<pID>4</pID>
</Row>
<Row>
<msgTxt>Test Message2</msgTxt>
<SendTime>2013-06-18T13:01:46</SendTime>
<pID>4</pID>
</Row>
<Row>
<msgTxt>Test Message1</msgTxt>
<SendTime>2013-06-18T09:22:49</SendTime>
<pID>3</pID>
</Row>
<Row>
<msgTxt>Test Message0</msgTxt>
<SendTime>2013-06-18T08:59:38</SendTime>
<pID>1</pID>
</Row>
</Rowset>
```

The jqGrid itself will have only the fields `msgTxt` and `SendTime` displayed (`pID` is a hidden field).  The grid will have a third column in it which would be for the dropdown/submit button.  For the rows with `pID` = 4 - those rows should display the dropdown box on each of those rows.  The row with `pID` = 3 should display a `submit` button.  The `pID` = 1 should have nothing displayed in column 3.  Following is a simplified version of my `colModel`.

```
colModel:[
    {name:"SendTime",index:"SendTime",width:col1width,align:"center",formatter:"date",formatoptions: {"srcformat":"ISO8601Long", "newformat":"Y-m-d H:i:s"},xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>SendTime",sortable:false},
    {name:"msgTxt",index:"msgTxt",width:col2width,align:"left",xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>msgTxt",sortable:false},
    {name:"action",
        width:col3width,
        align:"center",
        title:false,
        formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                var pri = $(rowObject).find("pID").text();
                if (pri === "4") {
                    return msgSelect;
                    }
                if (pri === "3") {
                    return "<input name='reviewedBtn' class='cbox' style='height:90%;width:60%' type='submit' value='Reviewed' />";
                    }
                else {
                    return ""
                    }
                }
        },
    {name:"pID",index:"pID",width:col4width,align:"left",xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>pID",sortable:false, hidden:true}
    ],
```

I have the following code in my `beforeSelectRow` to trap the opening & the changing of the dropdown box.

```
beforeSelectRow: function(id, e) {
    var $self = $("#myGrid");
    var $td = $(e.target).closest("td");
    var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]);
    var name = $(e.target).attr("name");
    if (this.p.colModel[iCol].name === "action") {
        if (name === "rlist") {
            selected = $(this).val();
            console.log("responselist open);
        $("#rlist").change(function(){
                var ritem = $(this[this.selectedIndex]).val();
                var ritemtext = $(this[this.selectedIndex]).text();
                console.log("response list changed " + ritemtext +  "   id = " + id);

                return false;
                });// response list changed
            return false;
        } // if rlist
        if (name === "reviewedBtn") {
            console.log("reviewedBtn clicked");
            return false;
            } // if reviewedBtn selected
    } // if Action Column
    return false;
}, // beforeSelectRow
```

In the data example above, for **row 1**, the dropdown functions as it should - I detect the opening of the dropdown and the changing of it.  However, if I open the dropdown on **row 2**, it detects the opening of the dropdown, but never the change event in the dropdown once a selection is made.  (Note:  I removed some code that refreshes the grid in order to simplify the code I posted.  However, where I have the `console.log` statements are where I am tracking what is supposed to happen).

All the examples of jqGrid I have seen thus far deal with editing the data, which I am not doing. I believe I am doing something wrong in the custom formatter, but I do not know what.  I would appreciate any help or suggestions as to how resolve this or how I am going about this incorrectly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving my own issue by finally figuring out that there wasn't anything wrong with the custom formatter & what it was doing. I restructured the `beforeSelectRow` as follows:

```
beforeSelectRow: function(id, e) {
    var $self = $("#myGrid");
    var $td = $(e.target).closest("td");
    var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]);
    var name = $(e.target).attr("name");

    if (name === "reviewedBtn") {
       console.log("reviewedBtn clicked");
       return false;
       } // if reviewedBtn selected

    if (($(e.target).val() !== null) && ($(e.target).val() !== "Reviewed")) {
    var ritem = $(e.target).val();
    var ritemtext = $(e.target).text(); 
    console.log("response list changed " + ritemtext +  "   id = " + id);   
    return false;
       }    


    if (this.p.colModel[iCol].name === "action") {
        if (name === "rlist") {
            selected = $(this).val();
            console.log("responselist open);
            return false;
        } // if rlist
    } // if Action Column
    return false;
}, // beforeSelectRow
```

I needed to determine when the `responselist` was open (I was using it to stop an interval, which was omitted for simplicity here) & then would catch when either the button was clicked or the dropdown had a selection made.

The code above was able to do that.